# what is " EIO=3&transport=polling&t= " in socket io

Tags: sockets, socket.io

"EIO=3&transport=polling&t="

A Full Example :
https://google.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OGkV-snV&sid=szUinCLJL9WftYZ8Bw_p

here what is use of transport = polling and what t sands for ? and Sid?

nb: if it's not common for all socket io server let me know.

I need a simple explanation for the socket io polling, t and Sid sands for.

Comment: @user253751 I need to know more socket connections

Comment: it's probably undocumented - the only source is probably the socket.io code, which *is* available to read

Comment: but I checked all of them, yes they have a little bit about EIO, transport but nothing about "t"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clone repositories like https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-engineio, https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-engineio,  and https://github.com/socketio/socket.io, then search the codebases, you'll find a `handle_request` function in server.py, where you may interpret the code and read the code comments. It indicates that `https://google.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OGkV-snV&sid=szUinCLJL9WftYZ8Bw_p` may be interpreted as parts of a URL as follows:

- `https://google.com/socket.io/` is the socket.io scheme/host/path for handling HTTP requests
- `EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OGkV-snV&sid=szUinCLJL9WftYZ8Bw_p` are the query string parameters that are preceded by a question mark `?`
- query string parameter key `EIO` is provided to represent the Engine.IO protocol version used by the client, which has a value of `3` in the example, so the Engine.IO web server determines whether that's a compatible version or not
- query string parameter key `sid` is the unique session id (see function `generate_id`) that is used to store the socket object for that session
- query string parameter key `transport` is provided with a value of `polling`, so the web server will check that its a valid transport (i.e. either `websocket` or `polling`). See here for more info https://socket.io/docs/v3/how-it-works/
- I also couldn't determine what query string parameter key `t` means, even the unit tests only focus on testing the query string parameters `EIO`, `sid`, and `transport`, but not `t`

Comment: here is an example where i learnt why its important for the EIO version used by the client to match the EIO version used by the server in order for it to connect https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/10412#issuecomment-1328164244